# Validate if struct variable is empty or not

Tags: go

First of all, look at the following code snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var para1 struct {
        email, addr string
    }

    para1.email = "test@test.com"

    if para1 != nil {
        fmt.Println(para1)
    }

}
```

When I compile this code, I've got the compiler error:

```
./struct_func.go:15: cannot convert nil to type struct { email string; addr string }
```

How can I validate if my struct variable, if nil or not? Or I have to validate of property like

```
if para1.email != nil {
    fmt.Println(para1)
}
```

Comment: Strings cannot be nil, only empty. but pointers to strings can be nil. so either check for an empty string, or make the field a pointer to a string (not recommended)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can compare the `struct` to its zero value. You can test the `string` for its zero (empty) value `""` or test for `string` length zero. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var para1 struct {
        email, addr string
    }
    para1Zero := para1
    para1.email = "test@test.com"
    if para1 != para1Zero {
        fmt.Println(para1)
    }
    if para1.email != "" {
        fmt.Println(para1.email)
    }
    if len(para1.email) != 0 {
        fmt.Println(para1.email)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{test@test.com }
test@test.com
test@test.com
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [The zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a
>   declaration or a call of make or new, and no explicit initialization
>   is provided, the memory is given a default initialization. Each
>   element of such a value is set to the zero value for its type: false
>   for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings, and nil
>   for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps. This
>   initialization is done recursively, so for instance each element of an
>   array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value is specified.

Comment: Terrible Go. Perl is much better and simpler! (:

Answer (score 5):

I know this has been quiet for a while, but a nice reusable way to validate that a struct is empty is to use the "reflect" built-in. It allows you to compare against an empty copy of your struct. Here is a version of your code using an `isEmpty` function based on reflect.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func isEmpty(object interface{}) bool {
    //First check normal definitions of empty
    if object == nil {
        return true
    } else if object == "" {
        return true
    } else if object == false {
        return true
    }

    //Then see if it's a struct
    if reflect.ValueOf(object).Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        // and create an empty copy of the struct object to compare against
        empty := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(object)).Elem().Interface()
        if reflect.DeepEqual(object, empty) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {

    var para1 struct {
        email, addr string
    }

    para1.email = "test@test.com"

    if isEmpty(para1) {
        fmt.Println("It's empty")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(para1)
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/geqHKMSWzp

Answer (score 3):

```
var para1 struct {
    email, addr string
}
```

After this line, `para1` is a struct value containing 2 empty strings [as you can see here](http://play.golang.org/p/ycJIe-LzOX).

only slices, maps, channels, pointers and functions can be `nil`. Therefore comparing `para1` to `nil` does not make sense and the compiler is complaining about that.

Admittedly the error message could be better.

If you want to know if `para1` is empty you should give its type a name and declare a method on it:

```
type Parameter struct {
    email, addr string
}

func (p Parameter) Empty() bool {
    return (p.email != "" && p.addr != "")
}
```